# Dockerfileをbuildしようとする以下のエラーが出力されます。

Tags: docker

Dockerfileを作成し、buildしようとすると以下のエラーが出力されます。

環境：
Windows 10 Home バージョン20H2ビルド19042.630
Ubuntu 18.04
Docker version 19.03.13

**実行したコマンド:**

```
docker build -t ubuntu:18.04 \PATH\
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
[+] Building 0.0s (2/2) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2B                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount985632545/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

**DockerFile**

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

#set up timezone
#https://sleepless-se.net/2018/07/31/docker-build-tzdata-ubuntu/
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tzdata
# timezone setting
ENV TZ=Asia/Tokyo

#print command
RUN set -x

#install utility command
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends wget sudo software-properties-common build-essential

#install jupyter
#https://daichan.club/linux/78323
RUN sudo apt-get update && \
    mkdir downloads && \
    wget -q https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-2018.12-Linux-x86_64.sh -P ./downloads/ && \
    bash ./downloads/Anaconda3-2018.12-Linux-x86_64.sh -b
ENV PATH $PATH:/root/anaconda3/bin
#setup jupyter
RUN jupyter notebook --generate-config && \
    sed -i -e "s/#c.NotebookApp.ip = 'localhost'/c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'/" /root/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py && \
    sed -i -e "s/#c.NotebookApp.allow_remote_access = False/c.NotebookApp.allow_remote_access = True/" /root/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

#install packages
RUN conda install -y -c conda-forge pystan

EXPOSE 8900
```

Answer (score 2):

Dockerfile のファイル名が "dockerfile" (すべて小文字) 等になっていませんか？

**D**ockerfile にリネームするか、`-f` オプションで明示的に Dockerfile を指定する必要があるようです。

**実行例:**

```
docker build -t ubuntu:18.04 -f dockerfile \PATH\
```

**参考:**

[dockerが build できない - teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/292726) の回答より

Comment: 解決致しました。ありがとうございます